# C++ STL priority_queue with struct Clearification

Tags: syntax, struct, priority-queue

I have looked over this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601973/stl-priority-queue-of-c-with-struct) which talks about using this method for comparison:

```
struct thing
{
    int a;
    char b;

    bool operator<(const thing &o) const
    {
        return a < o.a;
    }
};

priority_queue<thing> pq;
```

On the other hand other uses method such as this:

```
struct Time {
    int h; 
    int m; 
    int s;
};

class CompareTime {
    public:
    bool operator()(Time& t1, Time& t2) // Returns true if t1 is earlier than t2
    {
       if (t1.h < t2.h) return true;
       if (t1.h == t2.h && t1.m < t2.m) return true;
       if (t1.h == t2.h && t1.m == t2.m && t1.s < t2.s) return true;
       return false;
    }
} 

priority_queue<Time, vector<Time>, CompareTime> pq;
```

While I logic myself with the first method, I don't quit understand the second method. Mostly because of the syntax. I am not quit sure what the overloading operator `operator()` means. What is that operator overloading?

Also, from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) on priority_queue, I don't quite understand the following, mainly the second parameter.

```
template < class T, class Container = vector<T>,
       class Compare = less<typename Container::value_type> > class priority_queue;
```

In another word, I don't understand the second method and its calling convention.

Also, what's the difference and which method is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not quit sure what the overloading operator operator() means.
>   What is that operator overloading?

What we have here is an overloading of the function call operator ([see SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689430/function-call-operator)) , this means that client code can 'treat' the `CompareTime` class instances as compare functions :

```
CompareTime ct;
if ( ct(t1, t2) ) 
{
...
}
```

> I don't quite understand the following, mainly the second parameter.

The [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) reference summarizes quite well , the template parameters :

- 0 arg - The type of the objects within the queue.
- 1 arg - The    underlying container/data structure for the queue, by
  default its the std vector
- 2 arg - Operation on priority queue relies on some precedence
  comparison, i.e. which item in the queue should be 'before' other item (see also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue%29) , so this arg accepts to have compare object (functor) which mean instances of plain class which overload the () operator  , the default is the std `less` functor which is simply a wrapper above the '<' semantics (boolean 2 valued function object).

// TEMPLATE STRUCT less

```
template<class _Ty>
struct less : public binary_function<_Ty, _Ty, bool>
{   
   // functor for operator<
   bool operator()(const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right) const 
   {    
         // apply operator< to operands
        return (_Left < _Right); 
    } 
};
```