# Difference in order with same comparator in Priority Queue & Vector

Tags: c++, vector, comparator, priority-queue

Following code uses same comparator function with vector and priority queue. However order produced by both data structures is different. I would like priority queue to behave in same way as vector.

I have two questions

1. Why is order different?
2. How can i make priority queue's order to be same as vector?

Here's the output of following code:

[image]

```
//Please ignore extra header files, I know I don't need them.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    typedef pair<string, int> PII;
    static bool cmp(const PII& a, const PII& b)
    {
        if (a.second == b.second)
            return a.first < b.first;
        return a.second > b.second;
    }
    void func(vector<string>& words)
    {
        unordered_map<string, int> hMap;
        for (const auto& w : words)
            hMap[w]++;
        std::priority_queue< PII, std::vector<PII>, std::function<bool(PII, PII)> > Q(cmp);
        vector<PII> V;
        for (const auto& e : hMap)
        {
            Q.emplace(e);
            V.emplace_back(e);
        }
        std::sort(V.begin(), V.end(), cmp);

        //Now why does order of elements is different in vector V and priority_queue Q, despite using same comparator function?
        int size = Q.size();
        cout << "Order in priority Queue:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            PII e = Q.top();
            cout << e.first << ":" << e.second << endl;
            Q.pop();
        }

        cout << "Order in vector:" << endl;
        for (const auto& e : V)
        {
            cout << e.first << ":" << e.second << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Solution s;
    vector<string> words = {"the", "day", "is", "sunny", "the", "the", "the", "sunny", "is", "is" , "we" , "we" , "we" };
    s.func( words );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quote from [cpreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) "Note that the Compare parameter is defined such that it returns true if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak ordering. But because the priority queue outputs largest elements first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last."

Comment: @Evg Why is it being closed as duplicate? I know how to use comparator for min heaps. This question is about the way comparator is interpreted by both data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Priority Queues and vectors use comparators differently. To understand the output of priority queue, you must understand its working. Priority Queue is effectively a heap with an element on top depending on the comparison function. To quote from [boost Priority Queue](https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/priority_queue.html)

> The comparison function used to determine whether one element is
>   smaller than another element. If Compare(x,y) is true, then x is
>   smaller than y. The element returned by Q.top() is the largest element
>   in the priority queue. That is, it has the property that, for every
>   other element x in the priority queue, Compare(Q.top(), x) is false.

In your case changing the comparison function to reverse the order should solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The order is different because `<` relation implies that `std::sort` sorts values in ascending order, and that `std::priority_queue` places the maximum element at the top. This is [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32748069).

If you want to reverse the order in the priority queue, you need another comparator that swaps the arguments,

```
bool cmp2(const T& a, const T& b) {
    return cmp(b, a);
}

//...
std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, decltype(&cmp2)> queue(cmp2);
```

This is in perfect analogy with going from `std::less` to `std::greater` as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2439283).

Instead of introducing a separate function, you can use a lambda:

```
auto cmp2 = [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return cmp(b, a); };
std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, decltype(cmp2)> queue(cmp2);
```