# Why Dijkstra + priority_queue performs worst compared to Dijkstra + queue?

Tags: algorithm, graph, queue, priority-queue, dijkstra

I solved this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jack-goes-to-rapture/problem) using Dijkstra with a normal queue instead of a priority queue because interestingly I was getting a TLE when I used the priority queue. My understanding is that Dijkstra with priority queue should perform better. I tried analyzing as to why is this the case?
I came up with a thought that it is so because the question uses test cases with graphs having edges from 1 to n in increasing order of their weights so it is a waste of time to maintain a priority queue and hence the TLE. I would like to know if this is exactly the case an I'm not missing anything. Here is my solution to the problem:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define INF 100000000
queue<pair<long, int>> pi;
vector<long> dist;
map<int, vector<pair<int, long>>> mp;

int main() {
  int m = 0, n  = 0;
  cin >> m >> n;
  while (n--) {
    int l = 0, k = 0, j = 0;
    cin >> l >> k >> j;
    mp[l].push_back(make_pair(k, j));
    mp[k].push_back(make_pair(l, j));  // for undirected edge
  }
  dist.assign(m + 1, INF);
  dist[1] = 0;
  pi.push(make_pair(0, 1));
  while (!pi.empty()) {
    pair<int, int> p = pi.front(); pi.pop();
    int u = p.second; long w = p.first;
    if (w > dist[u]) continue;
    for (auto e : mp[u]) {
      if (max(dist[u], e.second) < dist[e.first]) {
        dist[e.first] = max(dist[u], e.second);
        if (e.first != m)
          pi.push(make_pair(dist[e.first], e.first));
      }
    }
  }
  if (dist[m] == INF) cout << "NO PATH EXISTS" << endl;
  else cout << dist[m] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change a default comparator of priority queue?
If not, then, of course, it would be slower

[How can I create Min stl priority_queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439283/how-can-i-create-min-stl-priority-queue)

Comment: Oh yeah! I cannot change it directly because I'm using a pair but instead I added negative of every key to get the same effect.